# Add a Year to each item in list or Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, count, addition

This question maybe trivial. How do I add a year starting with 1903 ending with 2009 to 106 items on a list without creating a long **HUGE** list of years
**But** bypass ones with a year?

For Example:

```
  States : Boston Americans, World Series Not Played in 1904, New York,  
           Chicago, Chicago, Chicago
           Pittsburgh, Philadelphia, Philadelphia,
           Boston, Philadelphia, Boston, Boston,Boston]`
```

To this:

```
  States : [Boston Americans:1903], [World Series Not Played:1904], [New York:1905],  
           [Chicago:1906],[Chicago:1907:],[Chicago:1908]....ect
```

While I know you can add a number count to each item on list

```
 d = defaultdict(int)
 for word in words.split():
     d[word] += 1
```

I tried:

```
 d = {}
 for i in new_list:
     d[1903 + i] += 1 # I know this looks crazy but this is all I have
     print(d)
```

I get

`TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

But this is new to me. I would normally have more to show but I really don't have any Idea
 how to code this at all.

Comment: oops let me change that.

Comment: The only tricky bit is removing the "in YYYY" part.  Do they all have the same format, i.e. ending with "in YYYY", or are some like "1994-- Cancelled due to Strike"?

Comment: At this point it doesn't matter as much as the year part. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list of winners, like:

```
>>> winners
['Boston Americans', 'World Series Not Played in 1904', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Pittsburgh', 'Philadelphia', 'Philadelphia', 'Boston', 'Philadelphia', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston']
```

You can use `enumerate` to associate these with numbers:

```
>>> list(enumerate(winners, 1903))
[(1903, 'Boston Americans'), (1904, 'World Series Not Played in 1904'), (1905, 'New York'), (1906, 'Chicago'), (1907, 'Chicago'), (1908, 'Chicago'), (1909, 'Pittsburgh'), (1910, 'Philadelphia'), (1911, 'Philadelphia'), (1912, 'Boston'), (1913, 'Philadelphia'), (1914, 'Boston'), (1915, 'Boston'), (1916, 'Boston')]
```

And from this you can make a dict, or a list of strings, or whatever:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(winners, 1903))
{1903: 'Boston Americans', 1904: 'World Series Not Played in 1904', 1905: 'New York', 1906: 'Chicago', 1907: 'Chicago', 1908: 'Chicago', 1909: 'Pittsburgh', 1910: 'Philadelphia', 1911: 'Philadelphia', 1912: 'Boston', 1913: 'Philadelphia', 1914: 'Boston', 1915: 'Boston', 1916: 'Boston'}
>>> ['{}:{}'.format(winner, year) for year, winner in enumerate(winners, 1903)]
['Boston Americans:1903', 'World Series Not Played in 1904:1904', 'New York:1905', 'Chicago:1906', 'Chicago:1907', 'Chicago:1908', 'Pittsburgh:1909', 'Philadelphia:1910', 'Philadelphia:1911', 'Boston:1912', 'Philadelphia:1913', 'Boston:1914', 'Boston:1915', 'Boston:1916']
```

You can strip the "in YYYY" part easily enough, but the best way to do that depends upon how variable the phrases are.

For example, if you know it's `in YYYY`, then you could use something like

```
def strip_year(winner, year):
    in_year = ' in {}'.format(year)
    if winner.endswith(in_year):
        winner = winner[:-len(in_year)]
    return winner
```

and then use a dictionary comprehension (python >= 2.7):

```
>>> {year: strip_year(winner, year) for year, winner in enumerate(winners, 1903)}
{1903: 'Boston Americans', 1904: 'World Series Not Played', 1905: 'New York', 1906: 'Chicago', 1907: 'Chicago', 1908: 'Chicago', 1909: 'Pittsburgh', 1910: 'Philadelphia', 1911: 'Philadelphia', 1912: 'Boston', 1913: 'Philadelphia', 1914: 'Boston', 1915: 'Boston', 1916: 'Boston'}
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose:

```
my_dict = {"States" : ["Boston Americans", "World Series Not Played in 1904", "New York",  
           "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago"
           "Pittsburgh", "Philadelphia", "Philadelphia",
           "Boston", "Philadelphia", "Boston", "Boston","Boston"]}
```

then this will do it:

```
years = 1906
for key in my_dict.keys():
  year_list = []
  for year in my_dict[key][0].split(","):
    if re.search(start,year):
      year_list.append(year)
    else:
      year_list.append(year + ":" + years)
    years += 1
  my_dict[key] = year_list
```

Answer (score 1):

something like that:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d in 1906','e']
>>> b = range(1903,1903+len(a))
>>> b
[1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907]
>>> zip(a,b)
[('a', 1903), ('b', 1904), ('c', 1905), ('d in 1906', 1906), ('e', 1907)]
>>> c = zip(a,b)
>>> d = [(i[0][:-7],i[1]) if i[0].endswith(str(i[1])) else (i[0],i[1]) for i in c]
>>> d
[('a', 1903), ('b', 1904), ('c', 1905), ('d ', 1906), ('e', 1907)]
```

and you may use `dict(d)` to get a dictionary afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's list comprehensions and define a helper function that joins the text with the years if they are not yet present.

You can use the optional second parameter of [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to indicate the *start* value – your first year.

```
def add_year_to(state, year):
    year = str(year)
    return state if state.endswith(year) else ':'.join((state, year))


states_with_years = [add_year_to(state, year) 
                     for year, state
                     in enumerate(states, 1903)]
```